# How to sort all data in a paginated data grid

Tags: apache-flex

I have paginated data grid having more than 5 pages (100 records/page) now i want to sort them all on just clicking on fields header

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found to do this is to implement this on the server side and have your web service call take parameters for range (or page number and page size) and sort order.  Then override the default behavior of the data grid headers to make service calls rather than sort the local data.

Comment: Correct.  There's no point in sorting the local data because it's paged data.